# why the sum fucntion can not work in XSLT1.0？

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I use 'sum function' to calculate the total quantity, the XML structure is a little complex, I searched online, sum function can be used in XSLT 1.0, but I tried it, it does not work for me, I do not know why?

my XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
<body>
<table border="1">
      <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
       </tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="warehouses/warehouse">
       <tr>      
          <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(items/item/s_qty)"/></td>     
       </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my XML :

```
<warehouses>
    <warehouse>
             <w_id>22</w_id>
             <w_name>Namekagon</w_name>
             <address>
                    <w_city>Indonesia</w_city>
                    <w_country>Indonesia</w_country>
             </address>
             <items>
                   <item>
                        <i_name>MECLIZINE HYDROCHLORIDE</i_name>
                        <s_qty>909</s_qty>
                    </item>
                </items>
      </warehouse>
      <warehouse>
             <w_id>21</w_id>
             <w_name>kagon</w_name>
             <address>
                    <w_city>Indonesia</w_city>
                    <w_country>Indonesia</w_country>
             </address>
             <items>
                   <item>
                        <i_name>MECLIZINE HYDROCHLORIDE</i_name>
                        <s_qty>587</s_qty>
                    </item>
                </items>
      </warehouse>
      <warehouse>
             <w_id>21</w_id>
             <w_name>kagon</w_name>
             <address>
                    <w_city>Singapore</w_city>
                    <w_country>Singapore</w_country>
             </address>
             <items>
                   <item>
                        <i_name>MECLIZINE HYDROCHLORIDE</i_name>
                        <s_qty>587</s_qty>
                    </item>
                </items>
      </warehouse>
```

the result should be: 1496

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want sum for all s_qty, you have to change

```
  <xsl:for-each select="warehouses">
       <tr>      
          <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(warehouse/items/item/s_qty)"/></td>     
       </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

see transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZW7

also you can use `<xsl:value-of select="sum(//s_qty)"/>`

Comment: Thank you so much!! by the way, if I add a condition such as in one specific country, warehouse[descendant::w_country='Indonesia'] , same like it can not work, do you know why?

Comment: can you share your input, as far i see your current input it didn't contain w_country='indonesia'

Comment: sure, I changed that XML, now it contains 'indonesia', my code is ```xsl:for-each select="warehouses">
       <xsl:if test="warehouse[descendant::country='Indonesia']">
       <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="warehouse/items/item/name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(warehouse/items/item/qty)"/></td>
       </tr>
       </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>```

Comment: see updated transformation at [https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZW7/1](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZW7/1), also as i see you use `descendant::country='Indonesia'` instead of `descendant::w_country='Indonesia'`